# Postgresql PSQL Exception in Inserting to database using Java

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I'm having an error in my code,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 12, number of columns: 11
```

I spent some time looking at different solutions but no avail.

This is my code where I have my sql string,

```
public void insertToDB(Active active) {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO active (branchname, branchcode, sidnew, sidold, accountno, openingbalance, "
                + "paymentreceived, currentcharges, monthlyrecrate, invoiceno, category)"
                + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        Connection conn = null;

        try {

            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps.setString(3, active.getBranchname());
            ps.setString(4, active.getBranchcode());
            ps.setString(5, active.getSidnew());
            ps.setString(6, active.getSidold());
            ps.setString(7, active.getAccountno());
            ps.setString(8, active.getOpeningbalance());
            ps.setString(9, active.getPaymentreceived());
            ps.setString(10, active.getCurrentcharges());
            ps.setString(11, active.getMonthlyrecrate());
            ps.setString(12, active.getInvoiceno());
            ps.setString(13, active.getCategory());

            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {}
            }
        }

    }
```

And here's the log from my eclipse console.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 12, number of columns: 11.
>           at com.joven.dao.ActiveDAOImpl.insertToDB(ActiveDAOImpl.java:74)
>           at com.joven.core.ActiveAccountsReadExcel.getExcelInfo(ActiveAccountsReadExcel.java:138)
>           at com.joven.core.ActiveAccountsReadExcel.ValidateExcelFormat(ActiveAccountsReadExcel.java:56)
>           at com.joven.core.ActiveAccountsReadExcel.buttonChooseFile(ActiveAccountsReadExcel.java:41)
>           at com.joven.ui.MainView$3.handle(MainView.java:110)
>           at com.joven.ui.MainView$3.handle(MainView.java:1)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
>           at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>           at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
>           at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
>           at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
>       Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 12, number of columns: 11.
>           at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:56)
>           at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setStringParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:118)
>           at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.bindString(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2310)
>           at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setString(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1398)
>           at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setString(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1384)
>           at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setString(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:135)
>           at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setString(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:135)
>           at com.joven.dao.ActiveDAOImpl.insertToDB(ActiveDAOImpl.java:67)
>           ... 49 more

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your query has only 11 `?` placeholders, you can't call `ps.setString` with an index > 11 .

Comment: Superb! I thought my `ps.setString` with indexes are the position in PostgreSQL table. Thank you! How do I accept it as answer?

Comment: I added this as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has only 11 `?` placeholders, you can't call `ps.setString` with an index bigger than 11.

The possible values range from `1` to `11` in your case.